What parameters do I use for ffmpeg to encode video for a Playstation 4 so that both video and audio work even in PSVR
I have seen parameters that work for video but the audio does not play. I'm trying to watch through PSVR. That's the first headset to come out for the play station 4 console.

What parameters are you trying? That would help us understand where your problems are caused.
